# Mvvmcross for Mac and plugin support for mac such as sqlite?

Tags: macos, sqlite, plugins, mvvmcross

I am new to the Mvvmcross and I think it looks like one of the best crossplatform development environment with great support. I only would like to know if there is an official Mac support for Mvvmcross and is there a plugin support for libraries such as sqlite, downloadcache and file in Nuget packages?

Answer (score 2):

The nuget and binary releases from the main MvvmCross repo don't today contain any Mac binaries.

A couple of MvvmCross contributors have done a lot of work for MonoMac and Xamarin.Mac - especially @deapsquatter and @tofutim

Their forks of MvvmCross might be the best place to look for their latest Mac code - e.g. https://github.com/loqu8/MvvmCross

There are some build "kludges" to get MonoMac and Xamarin.Mac to build on a PC - http://tofutim.blogspot.com/2013/11/adding-monomac-and-xammac-to-visual.html

For nuget distribution of MonoMac and Xamarin.Mac I'm afraid we haven't yet seen a good solution - see comments and discussions on https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/502 and https://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/532163

Comment: Thank you very much Stuart, I try to follow all your Mvvmcross tutorials and thanks for the info on Mac support for Mvvmcross. I hope this will get better by the time.